# Printing pyramid of numbers ordered clockwise

Tags: python

I am struggling with this python coding challenge and can't find anywhere online of someone covering this topic in more detail.
What the aim of the program is to print a pyramid of numbers in which the user has to specify what number it starts and where it ends. However, the order of the pyramids has to be clockwise from the top. For instance, the user wanting to start with the number 1 and finish at 10 the program will print;
(look at the image for how the pyramid is supposed to look like). In addition, the program only takes the last digit of numbers so the numbers are only 0-9.This is how the pyramid is supposed to look like:

[image]

```
n = int(input("enter number"))
num = 1
k = 1 * n
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, k):
        print(end=" ")
    k -= 1
    for j in reversed(range(1, i + 1)):
        print(num, end=" ")
        num +=1
    print("\r")
```

This is what I have so far I know I'm far off but I don't know what more I can do.

Comment: Do you need an image as output?

Comment: no just the numbers in order. The output console is what I'm trying to get.